# Need help finding logic flaw in array of integers to find pairs of K different pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, hashmap, set

Trying to solve the below:

Given an array of integers and an integer k, you need to find the number of unique k-diff pairs in the array. Here a k-diff pair is defined as an integer pair (i, j), where i and j are both numbers in the array and their absolute difference is k.

Example 1:
Input: [3, 1, 4, 1, 5], k = 2
Output: 2
Explanation: There are two 2-diff pairs in the array, (1, 3) and (3, 5).
Although we have two 1s in the input, we should only return the number of unique pairs.

Example 2:
Input:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], k = 1
Output: 4
Explanation: There are four 1-diff pairs in the array, (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4) and (4, 5).

Example 3:
Input: [1, 3, 1, 5, 4], k = 0
Output: 1
Explanation: There is one 0-diff pair in the array, (1, 1).

I have written the following code:

```
const findPairs = (nums, k) => {
    let count = 0
    if (k < 0) return 0
    if (k === 0) {
        const hash = {}
        for (let num of nums) {
            hash[num] = (hash[num] || 0) + 1
        }
        nums = Object.keys(hash)
        for (let num of nums) {
            if (hash[num] > 1) count++
        }
    } else {
        let numSet = new Set(nums)
        nums = Array.from(numSet)
        for (let num of nums) {
            if (numSet.has(Math.abs(num + k))) {
                count++
                numSet.delete(Math.abs(num + k))
            }

        }
    }
    return count
}
```

The test cases all pass except the last one:

```
console.log(findPairs([3, 1, 4, 1, 5], 2)) //2
console.log(findPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1)) //4
console.log(findPairs([1, 3, 1, 5, 4], 0)) //1
console.log(findPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], -1)) //0
console.log(findPairs([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 0)) //1
console.log(findPairs([1, 3, 1, 5, 4], 0)) //1
console.log(findPairs([-1, -2, -3], 1)) //2  my code returns 0 incorrectly
```

Need help figuring out logic flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Math.abs` call will mean that `count` only gets incremented when a matching element is found which is *positive* or zero. In the last example, you have negative elements. If you remove the `Math.abs`, your code works:

```js
const findPairs = (nums, k) => {
    let count = 0
    if (k < 0) return 0
    if (k === 0) {
        const hash = {}
        for (let num of nums) {
            hash[num] = (hash[num] || 0) + 1
        }
        nums = Object.keys(hash)
        for (let num of nums) {
            if (hash[num] > 1) count++
        }
    } else {
        let numSet = new Set(nums)
        nums = Array.from(numSet)
        for (let num of nums) {
            if (numSet.has(num + k)) {
                count++
                numSet.delete(num + k)
            }

        }
    }
    return count
}

console.log(findPairs([3, 1, 4, 1, 5], 2)) //2
console.log(findPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1)) //4
console.log(findPairs([1, 3, 1, 5, 4], 0)) //1
console.log(findPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], -1)) //0
console.log(findPairs([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 0)) //1
console.log(findPairs([1, 3, 1, 5, 4], 0)) //1
console.log(findPairs([-1, -2, -3], 1)) //2
```